# Get Unique FormGroup/Control Value Without Using getRawValue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a main component that hands back copies of the current form contents. But I'm not sure how to get the value from an angular FormGroup without sharing a reference to the `value` of the group it was called on. So if a copy is retrieved via `.value` and modified by some other component, and then the main component is asked for another copy it hands back the version that was modified by something else.

From the docs on [value](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) it seems like it should always be a copy of the current value inside the actual FormControls. But that is not the case and changes made to the result of calling `.value` continue to update the value of the FormGroup. eg:

```
var formValue = this.personForm.value;
formValue.name = 'Update assumed local copy'
```

gives the seemingly bizarre all `true` results:

```
formValue.name === 'Update assumed local copy'
this.personForm.value.name === 'Update assumed local copy' // What?
```

I ran across `getRawValue()` which does work how I'd expect it to, but it also includes disabled controls which I don't want. I only want the values that would be present in `.value`, but I want a unique instance returned like `getRawValue()`.

I'm guessing I could probably get away with using JSON stringify/parse but that felt pretty nasty and I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious here.

Here's an [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8njpwj) I threw up that shows a lot of the weirdness I'm experiencing.

Comment: if you want to change the value use **setValue**, if you want a copy you can use spread operator: `const value={...form.value,phones:form.value.phones.map(x=>{...x})}` or `const value={..form.getRawValue(),phones:form.value.phones.map(x=>{...x})}`

Comment: @Eliseo I'm well aware of the AbstractControl methods for manipulating the data.And there's no need to spread with getRawValue(), since it does return a copy already (shown in the stackblitz). And given our complex dynamic forms manually spreading would be impossible, and recursively travelling the object is something I was hoping to avoid. Still not sure how they intended .value to ever be used while it behaves like this.